# How would I write a Python script to compare two folders and delete the ones that aren't in both

Tags: python

I have two folders that are supposed to have the same filenames except one folder is all JPG and the other is JSON. There are many extra JPGs.

I know I have to do something like val.split('.') for val in os.listdir() and os.remove() or something, but can't figure out the syntax.

I want to iterate over both folders, and if there are any extra JPGs that don't have a corresponding JSON, I want to delete that JPG.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but you can implement something like:

```
#DirA files have .jpg extension
dir_a = []
#DirB files have .json extension
dir_b = []
for fileA in os.listdir(path_to_dir_a):
  dir_a.append[fileA.split('.')[0]]
for fileB in os.listdir(path_to_dir_a):
  dir_b.append[fileB.split('.')[0]]

for fileA in dir_a:
  if not fileA in dir_b:
    os.remove(os.path.join(path_to_dir_a,(fileA+'.jpg')))
```